# Get maximum values relative to the current index in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Let me say I have a DataFrame where the data is ordered with respect to time. I have a column as weights and I want to find the maximum weight relative to the current index. For example the max value found for the 10th Row would be from elements 11 to the end.

I ended up writing this function. But performance is a big threat.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"time":[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800],"weights":
[120,160,190,110,34,55,66,33]})
totalRows=df['time'].count()
def findMaximumValRelativeToCurrentRow(row):
 index= row.name
 if index!= totalRows:
    tempDf = df[index:totalRows]
    val=tempDf['weights'].max()
    df.set_value(index,'max',val)
 else:
    df.set_value(index,'max',row['weights'])

df.apply(findMaximumValRelativeToCurrentRow,axis=1)
print df
```

Is there any better way to do the operation than this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: given...updated the question with an enhanced code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for reverse order:

```
print (df['weights'].iloc[::-1])
7     33
6     66
5     55
4     34
3    110
2    190
1    160
0    120
Name: weights, dtype: int64

df['max1'] = df['weights'].iloc[::-1].cummax()
print (df)
   time  weights    max  max1
0   100      120  190.0   190
1   200      160  190.0   190
2   300      190  190.0   190
3   400      110  110.0   110
4   500       34   66.0    66
5   600       55   66.0    66
6   700       66   66.0    66
7   800       33   33.0    33
```

Comment: What exactly is iloc[::-1] doing?

Comment: Also works `df['max1'] = df['weights'][::-1].cummax()`